# FASM - Criar e executar arquivo em lote

Tags: assembly

Em Assembly(usando montador FASM), gostaria de criar um arquivo .bat e, em seguida, executa-lo.

Consigo criar o arquivo normalmente usando as funções contidas em msvcrt.dll.
Eu fecho o arquivo e tento executar usando system, mas nada ocorre(nem mesmo uma mensagem de erro)

O arquivo é criado corretamente.
Seção de código do programa:

```
main:
push mode ; w
push fileN ; run.bat
call [fopen]

pop [fileP] ; pego o endereço do stream do arquivo e jogo em fileP

push [fileP] ; coloco novamente o valor na pilha, para o fwrite
push eax
mov eax, 85 ; número de valores para escrever
push eax
mov eax, 1 ; tamanho em bytes de cada valor
push eax
push dataB ; conteúdo do arquivo batch
call [fwrite] ; -> até aqui tudo ok

push [fileP] ; endereço stream do arquivo
call [fclose] ; Creio que funcione corretamente

push pExec ; string contento os comandos pada executar
call [system] ; executado corretamente, mas não executa o .bat
call [exit]
```

Presumi que poderia não estar fechando o arquivo corretamente, ou que no tempo de execução o arquivo ainda não estaria fechado(por delay do sistema)

Tentei ao usar system utilizar o timeout, de qualquer forma nada ocorreu.(exceto a execução do timeout)

Pensei em usar sleep, mas não sei como usar em ASM. (Também já tentei fazer delay com um loop, mesmo resultado.)

Alguém saberia dizer o erro?

Mais alguns detalhes:
Estou montando para 32bits, o S.O. é o Windows 7 64 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei descobrindo o erro.(isto que dá ser teimoso e não usar a macro cinvoke >.<)

Na verdade a função retorna valores em eax, e estava pegando o valor da pilha. Escrevia corretamente pois estava dando push eax(jogando o endereço do stream de forma correta para o fwrite)

Me confundi na hora de escrever isso, e por isso acabou dando este resultado.
No fim das contas, o erro estava mesmo ao fechar o arquivo.

O código correto:

```
main:
push mode ; w
push fileN ; run.bat
call [fopen]

mov [fileP], eax ; pego o endereço do stream do arquivo e jogo em fileP
push eax ; jogo na pilha para o fwrite
mov eax, 85 ; número de valores para escrever
push eax
mov eax, 1 ; tamanho em bytes de cada valor
push eax
push dataB ; conteúdo do arquivo batch
call [fwrite]

push [fileP] ; endereço stream do arquivo
call [fclose]

push pExec ; string contento os comandos para executar
call [system]
call [exit]
```